# Send multiple httpRequest by different proxies

Tags: java, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using **HTTPClient Fluent API version 4.3.2** to send multiple request to various addresses defined by user. Each address will use its particular proxy setting. Below is my current code:

```
try {

            final Executor executor = Executor.newInstance().auth(proxy, userName, passWord);
            System.out.println(executor.execute(Request.Get(uri).viaProxy(proxy)).returnResponse().getStatusLine());
        } catch (final Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
```

I am facing a problem, when I connect to **Address 1** with **Proxy 1** (**correct** value of proxy username and proxy password), the request send properly as expected.

But when I add **Address 2** with **Proxy 1** (**wrong** value of proxy username and proxy password), with the expectation is request will fail, but it still connect successfully.

I though that after send request through a proxy, the very first proxy setting was cached somewhere in JVM, and I can not set another proxy setting for another request.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying setting proxy prior to request execution

```
Executor executor = Executor.newInstance().auth(proxy, userName, passWord);
System.out.println(executor
  .viaProxy(proxy)
  .execute(Request.Get(uri))
  .returnResponse().getStatusLine());
```

Comment: Thanks oleg, it helped me. Sorry for late response!!